# Context menu of zero size in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I try to bind context menu to my jsTree.

[Not so helpful JSFiddle, because context menu works in it](http://jsfiddle.net/Marboni/rTVZb/)

I added *contextmenu* plugin, but menu is not shown on right button click. So I debugged the function that renders context menu and found that height and width of the menu element is 0. I also debugged an example on [this page](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu) and found that height and width are positive.

```
// Height and width are 0 in my app and jsTree example.

$.vakata.context.cnt
    .html(html) // Default menu, so HTML in my app and in example are the same.
    .css({ "visibility" : "hidden", "display" : "block", "left" : 0, "top" : 0 });

...

h = $.vakata.context.cnt.height(); // 0 in my app, > 0 in example.
w = $.vakata.context.cnt.width(); // 0 in my app, > 0 in example.
```

What is a possible cause?

**RESOLVED**

When application initializes, it cleans jsTree's  that created to show context menu.

Sorry to disturb.

Comment: please provide an exemplary jsfiddle

Comment: @Alp, I provided example, but my problem is that context menu doesn't work in my app, issue is not reproduced in jsFiddle.

Comment: @Marboni According to your last comment, there **must be a bug in your application**. No one can help you with this issue unless you provide us the full source. You have *wasted* 100 reputation btw...

Comment: You are right, @cept0, I found the cause. jsTree creates div on document ready, then my application cleaned body to repaint layout. I paid 100 reputation to learn how to ask correct questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you must check the page with JavaScript debugger, may be FireBug or Chrome in built.. that will help you in identifying exact error,

As you have solved this error, I am not suppose to re-answer, but you may call this function after the application loaded,

$(function () {
2
    $("#demo1").jstree({
3
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu" ]
4
    });
5
});

as this is jQuery dependent

in future don't forget to use this

`<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>`

as this is most important option available... to avoid conflicts..(as some functions with same name may cause conflict, but jQuery works smartly after calling this function..

I am sure this may be the only reason, as in jsfiddle it worked fine..

In case of bounty points, you can award it in fraction.. so you can award part of(100) who have given you satisfactory answer..

I hope this will help.. :)